# supabase select on nested entity

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-js

I am using Supabase and can use the client to retrieve nested data. However, I cannot work out how to select WHERE an Id matches a foreign key on the top level select.

Here is the query:

```
const {data} = await client
  .from("teacherclasses") 
  .select("classrooms(rooms(roomId:id, roomName:displayname)), schoolclasses(id,reference, 
       totalPupils:totalpupils, subjects(subject:name, 
       subjectAbbreviation:abbreviation))",
  .eq("teacherid", teacherId)
  .eq("classrooms.isdefault", true)
  .limit(1, {foreignTable: 'classrooms'})
  .limit(1, {foreignTable: 'schoolclasses.subjects'})
```

This query works perfectly (if I use the actual teacherid in teacherclasses.

However the id I get from the frontend is the userid of the teacher, not its primary key.

I tried to change it as follows:

```
const {data} = await client
  .from("teacherclasses") 
  .select("teachers(userid), classrooms(rooms(roomId:id, roomName:displayname)), schoolclasses(id,reference, totalPupils:totalpupils, subjects(subject:name, 
       subjectAbbreviation:abbreviation))",
  .eq("teachers.userid", teacherId)
  .eq("classrooms.isdefault", true)
  .limit(1, {foreignTable: 'classrooms'})
  .limit(1, {foreignTable: 'schoolclasses.subjects'})
```

change: **teachers(userid)** and **.eq("teacher.teacherid", teacherId)**
however, this just returns every row in teacherclasses.

I don't need to select any data from the teacher table, but I get an error, if I do not add the teachers to the .select. I don't want to expose the teacherId, but cannot see how to do this

I am converting this from a dotnet LINQ query and here is a snippet that so you understand what I am doing

```
var schoolClasses = await _context.TeacherClasses
   .Include(t => t.Teacher)
   .Include(t=> t.ClassRooms)                    
   .Include(s => s.SchoolClass)
   .ThenInclude(s => s.Subject)
              
   .Where(t => t.Teacher.UserId == teacherId)
```

If anyone can see where I am going wring, I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be, that supabase is doing an outer join by default in this case.

Try replacing your join for teachers `teachers(userid)` in the select with `teachers!inner(userid)`, which will do an inner join and should only fetch the desired rows.

Not sure why this is not documented more prominently in the supabase documentation, as I couldn't find a link for this to the official documentation.

Closest thing I could find is this github issue: https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/197

Comment: @astoicoder - thank you. I had to do classrooms!inner too as well, but this answer got me to where I needed to be

Comment: Good one! Glad that it worked :)